# random sample of size N in Athena

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to obtain a random sample of `N` rows from Athena. But since the table from which I want to draw this sample is huge the naive

```
SELECT
id
FROM mytable
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 100
```

takes forever to run, presumably because the `ORDER BY` requires all data to be sent to a single node, which then shuffles and orders the data.

I know about [`TABLESAMPLE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) but that allows one to sample some percentage of rows rather than some number of them. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What type of connector are you using? On a hive connector, I get slightly different rows each time I run a simple `SELECT * FROM t LIMIT 10`. It is biased towards newer data, I assume because a different node wins the "race" to return results each time. How unbiased does your sample need to be?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Athena is actually behind Presto. You can use TABLESAMPLE to get a random sample of your table.

Lets say you want 10% sample of your table, your query will be something like:

`SELECT id FROM mytable TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(10)`

Pay attention that there is BERNOULLI and SYSTEM sampling.
[Here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) is the documentation for it.

Comment: Athena supports only `BERNOULLI` sampling. Console test shows that `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM` is a no-op.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Does no-op mean it doesn't require any extra processing?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer of using TABLESAMPLE works great with one small caveat: the resulting table's rows are sorted in the same order as the original table.

The original question on this page (and I myself) seems to want the new table to have randomly ordered rows. I achieved with a small extra clause at the end: `SELECT id FROM mytable TABLESAMPLE BERNOULLI(10) ORDER BY random()`